# sending parameters to controller from jquery through url

Tags: jquery, spring

sending parameters to controller through jquery
this is an url

```
var productsApiUrl = CTX_PATH + "/productProgramsDataTable"
```

and i want to send additional parameters along with this url but those parameters are not part of this url.

```
var productStatusType = $("#status_Type_for_products").val();
var productStatusForEachProduct = $("#status_Type_for_each_product").val();
```

these are the two parameters which i want to send along with url to the controller.

i am sending like this:

```
var productsApiUrl = CTX_PATH + "/productProgramsDataTable" + productStatusType + "," + productStatusForEachProduct;
```

is this a right way???

waiting for your suggestions...
Thank you very much...

Comment: Have you heard of something called `querystring`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var productsApiUrl = CTX_PATH + "/productProgramsDataTable?productStatusType=" + productStatusType + "&productStatusForEachProduct=" + productStatusForEachProduct;
```

Comment: Then each time you want to send more parameters, you add param5=valParam5&param6=valParam6&param7=valPama7 ..etc

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters through query string in the url.
Start the query string with a question mark "?".
Each param can be specified with a key value pair. eg: name=xyx
each keyvalue pair can be separated by "&". eg: name=xyz&age=27

```
var productsApiUrl = CTX_PATH + "/productProgramsDataTable/?productStatusType=active&productStatusForEachProduct=active";
```

Make sure that the webserver/ api accepts and is able to parse the query string to return the results.